# Spring перезаписывает объекты в коллекции

Tags: java, spring, коллекции

Доброго времени суток!

Ситуация в следующем: Есть класс Word с двумя стринговыми полями (код упрощен до самой сути)

```
public class Word{

private String targetWord;
private String description;

//getters, setters etc...
```

}

И класс в котором храниться коллекция экземпляров Word с методом Add который добавляет объект в коллекцию

```
public class Dictionary{

private ArrayList<Word> wordList;


public Dictionary(ArrayList<Word> wordList) {
    this.wordList = wordList;
}

public void addWord(Word word) {
    wordList.add(word); 
}

//etc...
```

}

В метод addWord объект поступает уже с инициализированными полями.

И наконец есть сервиc в который инъектятся зависимости и в котором вызывается вышеуказанный метод Dictionary.addWord

```
@Component
public class DictionaryService {

private final Dictionary dictionary;
private Word wordEntity;

public DictionaryService(Dictionary dictionary, Word wordEntity) {
    this.dictionary = dictionary;
    this.wordEntity = wordEntity;
}


 public void addWord(String word, String description){

    wordEntity.setTargetWord(word);
    wordEntity.setDescription(description);

    System.out.println(wordEntity.hashCode());

    if (checkWord(wordEntity) {
        dictionary.addWord(wordEntity);
    }
    
}
```

Но когда отрабатывает метод addWord то в коллекции перезаписываются все уже записанные ранее объекты на идентичные последнему

класс Main

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Main {


@Bean
Dictionary dictionary(){
    return new Dictionary();
}



@Bean
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
Word word(){
    return new Word();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Main.class);
    ReaderAndView reader = context.getBean(ReaderAndView.class);
    reader.start();

}
```

}

Comment: А что внутри ReaderAndView? походу там вызавается addWord

Comment: Внутри  ReaderAndView логика обработки консольных команд (приложение консольное), да там тоже есть метод  addWord но там просто считывание с консоли -> пихание в стрингу -> передача стрингов в Dictionary.addWord через валидатор который находится в DictionaryService

Comment: Тоесть логика какая: из ReaderAndView две стринги уходят в DictionaryService там они сетятся в инъектнутый объект word и дальше передаются в Dictionary.addWord(word) для записи в коллекцию

Comment: вы написали что "Но когда отрабатывает метод addWord то в коллекции перезаписываются все уже записанные ранее объекты на идентичные последнему" походу колекция не была пустой, как туда добавлялись обекты до вызова addWord, который по вашему перезаписал все уже существующие объекты на последний добавленый с помощью addWord

Comment: Первый вызов метода addWord добавляет объект word в коллекцию а второй вызов метода тоже добавляет объект в коллекцию но переписывает поля первого объекта дублируя свои

Comment: 1 итерация - добавляем mama mama
вывод - 
mama mama;
2 итерация - добавляем papa papa
вывод - 
papa papa;
papa papa;

Comment: метод addWord  работает в цыкле?

Comment: Нет, при добавления в коллекцию цикл не используется

Comment: Изначально консольное приложение без спринга работало как надо, но при переводе на спринг без изменения логики это появилось

Comment: я незнаю как решить проблему не увидев код в котором вызывается метод, который по вашим словам привел к ошибке

Comment: добавте код будет проще

Comment: Добавил код сервиса в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Component
public class DictionaryService {

private final Dictionary dictionary;
//Ваш сервис хранит сылку на обькт Word wordEntity
// а он должен создавать новый обжект типа Word 
// и в методе addWord сетить уже новую сылку

private Word wordEntity;

public DictionaryService(Dictionary dictionary, Word wordEntity) {
  
    this.dictionary = dictionary;
    this.wordEntity = wordEntity;
}


 public void addWord(String word, String description){

  Word newWord = new Word ();
  newWord.setTargetWord(word);
  newWord.setDescription(description);

    

    System.out.println(wordEntity.hashCode());

    if (checkWord(wordEntity) {
        dictionary.addWord(wordEntity);
    }
    
}
```